# How to automatically work around GUI on OS X/linux?

Tags: macos, audio, automation, applescript

I have a non-open-source GUI program on OS X which has a menu button to open a file in one format (example.X), and another menu button to export a rendering of that file in another format (example.Y).  This is not a conversion that could be done by myself or by any other tool I've found, as the rendering involves extensive digital audio synthesis.

I have a folder of 100 files of type X, and I want a convenient way to convert each .X file into a .Y file without manually opening and exporting each in the GUI.  Literally just two simple commands which don't require interfacing with the GUI - one to open the file, and another to render it out.

Is there a general way to achieve the effect of opening a program, running some commands from the menu, and then exit via the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Use AppleScript, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492839/applescript-on-clicking-menu-bar-item-via-gui-script

Comment: `pyautogui` would be ideal... https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Comment: Automator.app has an option to record and playback GUI interactions. Crude, but may be sufficient for your needs.